# How To Delete All Records From Database All Tables

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Can you guys help me solve my issue? How To Delete All Records From Database All Tables in a single click using Laravel ajax.
I have to delete all records from all tables, please help to solve my issue.

Thanks in advance

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu6Qg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You should try this**

**In ajax**

```
$(document).on('.delete-all-record', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Some problem occurred, please try again.");
        }
    });
});
```

**In Controller**

```
$tableNames = DB::select('SHOW TABLES');
foreach ($tableNames as $name) {
    //if you don't want to truncate migrations
    if ($name->Tables_in_db_name == 'migrations') {
        continue;
    }
    if ($name->Tables_in_db_name == 'users') {
        continue;
    }
    DB::table($name->Tables_in_db_name)->truncate();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer...But get this error "Undefined property: stdClass::$Tables_in_db_name" please tell me what is Tables_in_db_name???

Comment: In `name->Tables_in_db_name` replace your `database name` with `db_name`!

Comment: but I don't want to truncate the table what I do for that? It's truncating my user table also please suggest me a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the truncate method, this works for Laravel 4 and 5:

```
MyModel::truncate();
```

It will delete your all data for your single table.

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

It will delete your all table's all data .it will refresh your all table's data

Answer (score 0):

using **Artisan::call()** 
create function in your controller

```
use Artisan;

public function refreshDatabase(){
   Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
   return 'Success';
}

Route::get('refresh', 'YourController@refreshDatabase');

$.ajax('/refresh',   
{
    success: function (data) {
           // you can write
    }
});
```

EDITED

in your **web.php** file use like below without using controller function,

if you really want use controller function then change function name

```
    use Artisan;
    Route::get('refresh-tables',function(){
       Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
           return 'Success';
    });

$.ajax('/refresh-tables',   
    {
        success: function (data) {
               // you can write
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello #hamelraj now it gives this message "Cannot declare class CreateContacts, because the name is already in use" why please tell

Comment: i thing above used class using somewhere i have edited answer check